# CKAN semantic search

Tags: ckan

I am seeking to implement semantic search capabilities within CKAN. That is, searching for a term or dataset would also show/retrieve related datasets. I found [Dataset relationships](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/Dataset-relationships) on the CKAN wiki but there is no documentation as to how to use it exactly, or any UI to show the relationships (via graph or tree view).

Any help or guidance is really appreciated. Would really like an existing extension, any guidance on how to go about building my own, or just a conversation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time I do not believe there is any real documentation or web UI for the Dataset relationships.

There is an [open Issue on the CKAN github repo](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/4212) about this and work is being done / considered.

There are a couple CKAN extensions that also help implement this web frontend such as https://extensions.ckan.org/extension/lire/, but there are a few others too.

I believe you'd have to implement the relationship (lets say with the API when adding datasets) and tie datasets together using existing tables. Then when you're querying datasets you can use the relationship to get the related datasets. *(search for data with X term in title, query it's relations, query those datasets).*

Answer (score 0):

The [`similar_datasets`](https://github.com/stadt-karlsruhe/ckanext-discovery#similar_datasets) plugin from the [ckanext-discovery](https://github.com/stadt-karlsruhe/ckanext-discovery) extension might suit your needs: it adds a box to the sidebar which lists datasets similar to the one the user is currently viewing. The similar datasets are automatically discovered using the similarity of their metadata.

<sup>Full disclosure: I'm the author of ckanext-discovery</sup>